# Take value, update field with output

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

My goal:
Is to take selected value run it through my function update field with output value of function.

Problem:
When I select the value from the list it's not firing the function and not updating the field.

Thank you for any help.

**HTML**

```
<form id="someform">
<select id="sample" onChange="dIIN()">
<option>12</option>
<option>14</option>
<option>16</option>
<option>18</option>
<option>20</option>
<option>22</option>
<option>24</option>
<option>27</option>
<option>30</option>
<option>32</option>
</select> 
</form>

<tr>
<td>Quantity to be dredged</td>
<td><input type="number" value="450000" class="" id="quantity-dredged" ></input></td>
</tr>
```

**JavaScript**

```
var dIIN = function() {
  var dredgeSize = document.getElementById('sample');
  var foo = 0;
  if (dredgeSize <= 12) {
    foo = 36;
  } else if (dredgeSize <= 14) {
    foo = 42;
  } else if (dredgeSize <= 16) {
    foo = 44;
  } else if (dredgeSize <= 18) {
    foo = 48;
  } else if (dredgeSize <= 20) {
    foo = 60;
  } else if (dredgeSize <= 22) {
    foo = 62;
  } else if (dredgeSize <= 24) {
    foo = 62;
  } else if (dredgeSize <= 26) {
    foo = 68;
  } else if (dredgeSize <= 28) {
    foo = 68;
  } else if (dredgeSize <= 30) {
    foo = 74;
  }
  document.getElementById('quantity-dredged').value = foo;
};
```

Here is a 
[codePen example](http://codepen.io/coryk/pen/mPpzLb?editors=1011)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the line:

```
var dredgeSize = document.getElementById('sample');
```

to:

```
var dredgeSize = document.getElementById('sample').value;
```

**[Demo](http://codepen.io/rmrinmoy/pen/PNEyBP?editors=1011)**

Answer (score 0):

You can use event listeners instead to keep your code clean.

```js
var dIIN = function(dredgeSize) {
  var foo = 0;
  if (dredgeSize <= 12) {
    foo = 36;
  } else if (dredgeSize <= 14) {
    foo = 42;
  } else if (dredgeSize <= 16) {
    foo = 44;
  } else if (dredgeSize <= 18) {
    foo = 48;
  } else if (dredgeSize <= 20) {
    foo = 60;
  } else if (dredgeSize <= 22) {
    foo = 62;
  } else if (dredgeSize <= 24) {
    foo = 62;
  } else if (dredgeSize <= 26) {
    foo = 68;
  } else if (dredgeSize <= 28) {
    foo = 68;
  } else if (dredgeSize <= 30) {
    foo = 74;
  }
  document.getElementById('quantity-dredged').value = foo;
};
   var select = document.querySelector('#sample');
    select.addEventListener('change', function(){
      dIIN(this.value);
    });
```

```html
<form id="someform">
<select id="sample">
<option>12</option>
<option>14</option>
<option>16</option>
<option>18</option>
<option>20</option>
<option>22</option>
<option>24</option>
<option>27</option>
<option>30</option>
<option>32</option>
</select> 
</form>

<tr>
        <td>Quantity to be dredged</td>
        <td><input type="number" value="450000" class="" id="quantity-dredged" ></input></td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
<form id="someform">
<select id="sample" onchange="dIIN(this)">
<option>12</option>
<option>14</option>
<option>16</option>
<option>18</option>
<option>20</option>
<option>22</option>
<option>24</option>
<option>27</option>
<option>30</option>
<option>32</option>
</select> 
</form>

<tr>
                                <td>Quantity to be dredged</td>
                                <td><input type="number" value="450000" class="" id="quantity-dredged" ></input></td>
</tr>
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
var dIIN = function(_this) {

  var dredgeSize = _this.options[_this.selectedIndex].text;
  var foo = 0;
  if (dredgeSize <= 12) {
    foo = 36;
  } else if (dredgeSize <= 14) {
    foo = 42;
  } else if (dredgeSize <= 16) {
    foo = 44;
  } else if (dredgeSize <= 18) {
    foo = 48;
  } else if (dredgeSize <= 20) {
    foo = 60;
  } else if (dredgeSize <= 22) {
    foo = 62;
  } else if (dredgeSize <= 24) {
    foo = 62;
  } else if (dredgeSize <= 26) {
    foo = 68;
  } else if (dredgeSize <= 28) {
    foo = 68;
  } else if (dredgeSize <= 30) {
    foo = 74;
  }
  document.getElementById('quantity-dredged').value = foo;
};
```